# What is the proper suffix for a deceased person?

Tags: grammar-dikduk

What do the different suffixes mean, what are the differences between them, and which suffix is used for which people?

Example: ז"ל, זצ"ל, זצוק"ל, זי"ע, נבג"מ

(This question differs from previously asked similar questions, since this question is asking when it is applicable to use which suffix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ז״ל: zikhrono livrakha (for a man) / zikhronah livrakha (for a woman) used for a holy or a righteous person

זצ"ל: zekher tzadik livrakha/ used for a holy or a righteous person (man)

זצוק"ל: zekher tzaddik v'kadosh livrakha    / righteous and holy person, not necessarily a martyr

זי"ע: zechuto yagen aleinu/ used for outstandingly holy person

נבג"מ: (נשמתו בגנזי מרומים; his soul in the heavenly vineyards)

See for more [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorifics_for_the_dead_in_Judaism).

[image]